# Plot city names for lon,lat coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot the names of cities onto a map of germany using the Basemap package.
I have specified the longitude and latitide values with:

```
Cname=Form_Cities["name"].values    
Clat=Form_Cities["lat"].values
Clon=Form_Cities["lon"].values
```

furthermore,

```
map=Basemap(projection="lcc",resolution="l",width=1E6,height=1E6,lon_0=9.9167,lat_0=51.5167,fix_aspect=False)#Resturn just the empty "figure with no conotents on it
map.shadedrelief()
map.drawcountries(color="black",zorder=1,linewidth=1)
```

and with:

```
ax.annotate(s=Cname,xy=(Clon,Clat),xycoords="axes pixels")
```

I want to plot the city names but it isnt working but returns the exception

> ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it like this:

```
x,y=map(Clon,Clat)
[ax.annotate(s=nme,xy=(xp,yp),color="gray",alpha=0.5,fontsize=6) for nme,xp,yp in zip(Cname,x,y)
```

but I still dont get why I have to transform the x and y coordinates with map(Clon,Clat) because actually Clon and Clat must represent the 
llcrnrlon   The lower left corner geographical longitude and
llcrnrlat   The lower left corner geographical latitude values if I follow the syntax of the Basemap method:

> mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap(llcrnrlon=None, llcrnrlat=None,
>   urcrnrlon=None, urcrnrlat=None, llcrnrx=None, llcrnry=None,
>   urcrnrx=None, urcrnry=None, width=None, height=None, projection=’cyl’,
>   resolution=’c’, area_thresh=None, rsphere=6370997.0, ellps=None,
>   lat_ts=None, lat_1=None, lat_2=None, lat_0=None, lon_0=None,
>   lon_1=None, lon_2=None, o_lon_p=None, o_lat_p=None, k_0=None,
>   no_rot=False, suppress_ticks=True, satellite_height=35786000,
>   boundinglat=None, fix_aspect=True, anchor=’C’, celestial=False,
>   round=False, epsg=None, ax=None)

but havent't I done this with:

```
Clat=Form_Cities["lat"].values
Clon=Form_Cities["lon"].values
```

or am I wrong?

Can please anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

You have to plot city names and markers for it in a cycle:

```
...
# convert your coords to map projection coords
yp,xp = map(yp,xp)
map.plot(xp, yp, 'ro', markersize=4) # plot markers
for label, xpt, ypt in zip(point_lables, xp, yp): # add annotation (city names)
   plt.text(xpt+0.5, ypt+0.01, label, color='firebrick', fontsize=7)
...
```